# Importing 'Keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, key

I am trying to execute the below code. I exclusively tried to import *Keys* from *webdriver*, but it still does not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.common.keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
page = driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
print (driver.title)
finder = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-field")
finder.send_keys("Python Test")
finder.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Output:

```
Welcome to Python.org
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Arvind/Desktop/Python Tests/selenium_tests.py", line 9, in
<module>
    finder.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
NameError: name 'Keys' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 35):

You need to have import like this,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

instead of

```
import selenium.webdriver.common.keys
```

Then your code would run fine.