# Import-error from Selenium Keys implementation

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I'm receiving an error on this line of code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

that says

> "Unable to import
> 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys'pylint(import-error)."

However, the program is executing as it would if there was no error. I understand "Keys" is case sensitive, which seems to be the most common error as per these previous questions on the topic: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835404/importing-keys-from-selenium-webdriver-common-keys) [Link 2](https://github.community/t/selenium-unable-to-import-keys/15391)

If it may have any effect, I'm using VSCode with the Python and MagicPython extensions and this is all of my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://amazon.com/")
print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_id("twotabsearchtextbox")
search.send_keys("glad")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

My last place to look is the Selenium documentation so if I figured it out I'll update.

Comment: That's not an error.  That's just a false positive from pylint.  Ignore it if you can.

Comment: @kanwoody -Since 'pylint' did not show this "import-error" in my test, have you tried to reload VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the code you provided in my PC, it not only works, but also does not display "import-error", (I have installed and used 'Pylint'), therefore, it is recommended that you reload VS Code so that 'Pylint' can load this module.

[image]

My environment:

VS Code Version: 1.54.1 (user setup);
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041;
VS Code extension: Python 2021.2; Jupyter 2021.3 ; Pylance 2021.3.0;

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```