# unable to import selenium.webdriver.common.keys Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver, key, selenium-webdriver-python

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

I'm trying to use selenium for studying crawling. Using M1 Mac.

I barely find answers to that error.

Does anyone know how to solve this in vs code?

When I run the code by typing %python google.py, it starts to open the website but it closes it right after.

I matched the version between chrome and chromedriver (mac-arm-64)(112.xx.xx.x.x.)

The code in copied from 'https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html'

Only the url was edited

I want to solve that error and let this code work fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the actual traceback of the error, you've provided no information as it is. Best guess with *NO* actual ability to support it because we don't know the error is that your chromedriver version isn't matching Chrome. Also, please don't post code as images, it makes it a lot easier for people to help you if you post the actual code as text

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43835441/14447614) solve your problem?

Comment: Still don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

That's Linting's warning, adding the following content in *settings.json* to close **Linting**.

```json
    "python.linting.enabled": false
```

Or search for `python.linting.enabled` on the **Settings** and then cancel the check.

[image]

*[More content about Linting.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)*

Comment: Still doesn't work. I disabled python linting in setting (through shift+command+p).
plus, I checked that my json file has that content above already. But still same error message.

Comment: I checked the selenium version and updated it, I tried import 'Keys' directly from 'selenium' but it still doesn't work. 
It also says 
"No name 'webdriver' in module 'selenium'"
I just can't understand what is the problem. Why my mac vscode can't import webdriver and Keys from selenium?

Comment: Check the ***user*** *settings.json* and the ***workspace*** *settings.json*.    https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson